# What would a society living on a rogue planet look and be like?

Tags: rogue-planets

I am a huge Doctor Who fan and one of my favorite Doctor who stories is Big Finish´s Doctor Who Spare Parts.
This story takes place on earth´s twin Mondas, the story is at some point in the past something happened to Mondas causing it to drift out of our solar system and into space.
This forced the native human population to go underground and live and build a city there.
As resources dwindled in a desperate attempt to survive they began to augment themselves with various cybernetic implants, slowly cutting away their humanity.

Now this is all sci-fi, but let's say a real world Mondas existed, a rogue planet that floated through interstellar space.
The humans living on the planet where technologically advanced enough for them to survive underground a la close if not slightly above our current technology.

What would their society look like?
I could imagine it would be very tightly controlled, as you would need to recycle as many resources as possible and at the same time prevent overpopulation, so a kind of eugenics might be introduced also.

What would the cities look like i could imagine that since space would be an issue we might see large two maybe three storage buildings with 3 or 4 families living in each one.

What would their diet consist off, i could imagine meat would be a luxury as space would probably be limited, so having anything but small animals like the pig species Kunekune wouldn´t be realistic as space would probably be limited.
So most of their diet might consist of algae and fungus.

Also what about things like electricity and other such things, where would they get that, maybe Geothermal energy could work, but i don´t know.
I could imagine nuclear energy wouldn't be very safe partially there´s the waste material, but also the cooling towers if anything goes wrong well that´s a hole to the surface with a frozen atmosphere, not something you would want to risk.

Also let's say that when their world started to drift out of the solar system the humans living on that planet looked like you and me same average height, weight, skin color etc etc.
How would they look after several generations living underground?

But again I don´t know, so how would a society living underground on a rogue world look like?
Also a side question I have heard that such societies would have a time limit as when the atmosphere finally froze, that´s it game over anything living on that planet would be dead.
That really doesn't make sense to me as any society advance enough to live underground, would have found a way to prevent loss of atmosphere where they live and replace the oxygen used.

Comment: Your question is good but I think it needs more focus, there's lots of questions there in my opinion, what exactly do you need to know? It's how would they look like after years underground or what they would eat or how do they get electricity, etc, etc ..

Comment: Hey Grid.  Take a look at the tour:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour  because what you wrote is more an open exploration of the scheme that interests you.  Ask one specific question.  You can ask one after another!  Also: "rogue"!  Rouge worlds are ruddy and maybe a little French.

Comment: There are already quite a few what-if-we-lived-underground questions, and many closely-related society-in-an-underground-bunker questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the society had sufficient warning and sufficient intent it might be possible to build an underground society that could survive on a rogue planet; however it would require huge amounts of electricity to power lighting for plant growth underground. Generating sufficient electrical energy would be a problem. Another major issue would be replacement parts.

Geothermal or nuclear would be options but both would have a limited life span, nuclear fuel would eventually run out and geothermal power would also eventually require re-drilling. Both might be possible but the difficulties would be enormous.

Ultimately the key issue would be the creation of a self sustaining society that could replace everything that it uses from drill heads to light bulbs. It might be possible but it would need a vast amount of work to ensure that all required chemicals, parts and machinery could be produced on demand. I doubt very much that it would be a practical proposition.

A better way to look at it would be how long could it sustain itself? Perhaps a few hundred years, but it depends on the exact details.